# How to re-randomize the colours from the brick texture node?

Tags: node-editor, shaders, procedural

I'm making wooden planks with the brick texture node and chose 2 grey colours. As far as I understand, it randomly picks a colour inbetween those two. My result contains a cluster of very similar boards, which doesn't look good.
I tried making a new brick texture node and using the applying the same settings, but the result doesn't change.
Is there a way to randomize the colours again?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure you can with the node as is. You can try to add color-affecting nodes after the brick texture node, like a RGB Curves, to play with the end result, or use color ramps as color inputs. But to me it looks like the colors are generated by a form of noise but we have no seed option for that noise. What you can also do, is using your Mapping node to move the texture, maybe you will find a portion that better suits your needs.

Comment: @L0Lock Thank you for the response. Found a portion via mapping node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit hacky but you can get new random values by feeding the output of the brick texture into a [White Noise](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/white_noise.html) texture node.

[image]

You can either use a math node to add an offset to the noise to modify the randomness, or set the White noise input to "4D" and tweak the W input, but this is more computationally intensive.

[image]

Edit: sorry for the non-colorblind friendly colors.